# Vectorized Subarray Covariance

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, covariance

My problem is I have a array[28][28] and it contains a subarray.
I should vectorize it first, and get the cov of a (k^2,k^2) dimension but The vectorisation is done. When I use the np.cov() function, it is just a value. What steps did I miss?

```
for i in indexes_cov:
   vectorized_points = np.reshape(data[i],-1) # get data at i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use typecast.

- Type Casting is the method to convert the variable data type into a certain data type in order to the operation required to be performed by users. (ref - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-casting-in-python-implicit-and-explicit-with-examples/)

Comment: Ok interessting. I said: vectorized.points.astype(float), after that I used np.cov() and changed nothing..